# Usage of halber / halben

Tags: grammar, word-usage

It is common to use *halber* to indicate a cause, a reason or an end for something.

> Der Einfachheit *halber* hier ein einfacher Beispielsatz.

Now 'Einfachheit' is feminine, so 'halber' is absolutely correct. For a masculine noun it would be:

> Des Friedens *halben* hier ein freundlicher Beispielsatz.

I feel very uncomfortable writing that. And I'd never use it in a conversation and I really only once heard it beeing used (and that was in a play from Goethe). Is it just uncommon or is it wrong to decline it? May masculine nouns be combined with 'halb'? Would it be (for some reason) more correct to not decline it and say:

> Des Friedens *halber* ein freundlicher Beispielsatz.

I know that I can always circumvent using it by using more common phrases. Still I'd like to know if there is something wrong with the masculine case. And if so: what.

Comment: "Des Friedens halber" does indeed sound weird, but not because it's wrong. There are alternatives, however.

Comment: I wouldn’t call *halber* anything close to “common”. It’s rather sophisticated (hence stylistically marked), as is the genitive case for most non-possessive uses, but *der Einfachheit halber* may count as a “common” fixed expression.

Comment: @Crissov I feel there are a lot of fixed expressions working with _halber_: der Ordnung halber, der Vollständigkeit halber, der Fairness halber, der Form halber... With so many fixed expressions build with it, _halber_ can hardly be that sophisticated, can it?

Comment: Actually it can if used productively, i.e. outside fixed expressions. That’s why *des Friedens halber* sounds weird to @Raphael. I agree, though, that there are other common combinators than just *Einfachheit*.

Comment: @Crissov I attributed the weirdness to the fact that _Frieden_ is masculine. Every commonly heard expression with _halber_ I can think of is feminine. But if you say it's sophisticated outside that expressions... well I take your word for it!

Comment: Well, it’s worse even, because *Frieden* hasn’t completely replaced *Friede* yet, so the old genitive form in *des Frieden halber* or *des Friedes halber* may sound more natural to some people. What about [*des Spaßes halber*](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/abfrage/)? Like *interessehalber* it’s probably better used without an article and written as one word. Interestingly, most frequent left neighbors of *halber* end with *+heit* or *+keit* (or foreign equivalents as in *fair+ness*), which are derivantemes that mandate feminine gender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"halber" does not (grammatically) derive from "halb" (as in "ein halbes Brot"). It's a [preposition](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/halber_aufgrund_fuer_wegen) that is not inflected.

> Des Friedens halber...
>
> Des Friedens wegen ...
>
> Des Friedens zuliebe ...
>
> Um des Friedens willen ...

These all mean the same thing and the preposition never changes with the gender of the noun.

Comment: But you do say _meinethalben_, don't you? That said, let me quote from Jacob Grimm, Deutsche Grammatik, Bd. 4, S. 797: "die nhd. form schwebt zwischen _halb_, _halben_, _halber_: meinthalben, ehren halber, des friedens halber, und wird oft noch mit der präp. _um_ verknüpft: _um des friedens halber_".

Comment: @Ingmar Yes, but that's just [another "fixed" word](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/meinethalben) that is not inflected. In particular, it is not associated with a noun in the sentence (it's point of reference is "ich" which is wrapped in the word itself).

Comment: So what you are saying is, that "des Friedens halber" is actually right? It surely feels very... well it makes me feel very uncomfortable, too. But thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Einer As far as I can tell, it is, yes. There are certainly no other forms of "halber" in this use case.

Comment: So good ol' J. Wolle Goethe took some [artistic freedom](http://www.arenhoevel-verlag.de/einzeltitel/joachim_dunkel_3.html) Wouldn't be the first time he did this. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Einer Neither am I sure that that "Halben" there means the same thing as you want "halber" to mean here (the grammar seems to suggest that the person avoided "Halben"), nor is Goethe always the best reference for German as spoken today. ;) But definitely a nice reference! (You're welcome!)